# Python 'from x import z' imports more than just 'z'

Tags: python

I recently came across some Python behavior regarding the import system that I really don't understand.

I have this directory structure:

```
.
└── foo
    ├── baz.py
    └── __init__.py
```

*baz.py*

```
def bar():
    return "hi"
```

*__init__.py*

```
from .baz import bar
```

Importing the module I noticed that the **baz** namespace is imported with the foo module, even though I would expect only **bar** to be in there because of the `from .baz import bar` line in __init__.py.

```py
>>> import foo
>>> dir(foo)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'bar', 'baz']
```

I've studied the structure of many popular python packages and though they use this exact syntax, they don't seem to show this behavior. Any ideas?